# Реализация мини-программы на C#

Tags: c#

При компиляции не выдает ошибку, а выдает не то что ожидалось, то есть когда я пишу число 7 компилятор выводит, что это строка, не подскажите в чем ошибка?

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static  void M(int i)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("это обычное число");
  }
  public static void M(string i)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("это строка");
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
     var b=Console.ReadLine();
     M(b);
  }
}
```

Comment: ReadLine всегда возвращает только строку, всё правильно

Comment: вы не так ,поняли, коде я прописал что если это целочисленная переменняая он выводит "это число",если же это строка то он должен выводить "это строка"

Comment: Если хочется определить, похоже ли значение в строке на число, см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-do-i-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number

Comment: Вы бы сами по такому названию поняли, о чем речь, в чем проблема? Замените

Comment: Все символы, считываемые из терминала, по умолчанию имеют тип String. Т.е. в Вашем случае переменная 'b' всегда String, и нужно делать проверки на числовое значение и вызывать нужный метод.

Comment: спасибо,и извиняюсь что дал не правильный заголовок первый раз на сайте

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите.

Когда `Console.ReadLine` читает текст ввода, он читает лишь введённые символы, и помещает их в строку. `Console.ReadLine` не проверяет, можно ли ваши символы интерпретировать как число или как что-то ещё.

Переменная `b` имеет тип `string`, всегда. На деле `var` не означает «угадай настоящий тип переменной», он означает «возьми тот тип, который в правой части выражения». А поскольку тип правой части выражения — `string`, то и тип `b` тоже `string`.

Следовательно, перегрузка с `int` не будет вызвана никогда.

---

Для того, чтобы выяснить, не содержится ли в введённой строке число, нужно воспользоваться методом `int.TryParse`:

```
if (int.TryParse(b, out int n))
    M(n);
else
    M(b);
```

Тут тип `n` — `int`, так что будет вызвана нужная перегрузка.